# md5_file() PHP different that Java MD5 for txt files

Tags: java, php, md5, md5sum, md5-file

I'm trying to develop a file updater for some files in a folder, to Sync an FTP server with a local folder, using Java on the client and PHP on the server side.

On the server side, I'm calculating the `md5_file($filename)` for the file and returning every of them on a JSON.

On Java, I'm checking first if the file exists in the local folder. If the file exists, then I check for the MD5 checksum to see if the file is exactly the same as the online one.

**The MD5 is not matching when checking .txt or .lua files. It's ok when checking other file types, as .dds texture files.**

The MD5 I'm using on Java is this:

```
private String md5(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);                
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int read = 0;
    try {
        while( (read = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, read);
        }       
        byte[] md5sum = digest.digest();
        BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(1, md5sum);
        String output = bigInt.toString(16);
        return output;
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to process file for MD5", e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to close input stream for MD5 calculation", e);
        }
    }
}
```

As an example, for a description.lua file, with the following contents:

```
livery = {
{"KC-130_fusel", 0 ,"KC-130_map_fus",false};
{"KC-130_wing", 0 ,"KC-130_map_wingS",false};
{"KC-130_wing_2", 0 ,"KC-130_map_wings_2",false};
{"KC-130_notes", 0 ,"KC-130_notes_empty",true};
{"KC-130_FPod", 0 ,"kc-130_map_drg",false};
}
name = "Spain ALA 31 TK.10-06"
countries = {"SPN"} -- and any others you want to add
```

**PHP md5_file($filename) = d0c32f9e38cc6e1bb8b54a6aca4a0190**

**JAVA md5(File) = 08bf57441b904c69e9ce3ca02a9257c7**

I've been trying to find a relation between those two codes to see what's making the difference, but have not find any. I have checked like 10 md5 scripts for Java and all of them give the same result.

Is there any way I can fix this?

**EDIT: Solution given on first comment: Change the Transfer type on the FTP Client to Binary to avoid changing txt files to ASCII encoding, changing their length and md5.**

Comment: Does your FTP client perhaps perform newline conversion (`\r\n` to `\n` or vice versa) when you upload text-y files? Perhaps try forcing it to use binary transfer on all file types.

Comment: @zenzelezz Looks like this was the problem: Filezilla was uploading the files on ASCII. When changing to Binary now it match. Although PHP is adding a leading 0 and Java is not doing it, but that's an easy fix. Thank you!

Comment: I just want to say I'm somehow amazed with the solution you've come up with to serialize a byte array as hexadecimal. Though as you pointed out, this won't display the leading zeroes.

Comment: @kumesana I found this code on a Stackoverflow or a website, I don't remember now. It's not my code.